# Scrape data using html dom and class names

Tags: php, dom

Here I am trying to get address and phone number from the web page. Here is the code which does not give any error but also not give any result.

Is there something wrong?

I am trying to get `address`, one `image` and `phone` from the page.

Here is code:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
function getData($url)
{
    print("$url\n");
    $root = new stdClass();
    $items = array();
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    if($html) {
        $containers = $html->find('div.mapbox div.mapbox-text strong.street-address address.address');
        foreach($containers as $container) {
            $comments = $container->find('address.address span');
            $item = new stdClass();
            foreach($comments as $comment) {
                $address.= $comment->itemprop; //append the content of each span
            }
            echo $address;

            $getphone = $container->find('span.biz-phone');
            $phone = $getphone->itempro;
        }   

        $Imgcontainers = $html->find('div.js-photo photo photo-1 div.showcase-photo-box img.a la beverly sills');
        echo $Imgcontainers->img;
    }
}

$url = 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/locanda-san-francisco?start='.$i.'';
$root = getData($url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `<address>` tag doesn't have `address` class so `$containers` returns empty. Use below code in your `if` condition

```
$containers = $html->find('div.mapbox div.mapbox-text strong.street-address address');
foreach($containers as $container) {
   $comments = $container->find('span');
   $item = new stdClass();
   foreach($comments as $comment) {
       $address.= $comment->itemprop; //append the content of each span
   }
   echo $address;

   $getphone = $container->find('span.biz-phone');
   $phone = $getphone->itempro;
}
$Imgcontainers = $html->find('div.js-photo photo photo-1 div.showcase-photo-box img.a la beverly sills');
echo $Imgcontainers->img;
```

Comment: thanks dude, but it gives ` streetAddressaddressLocalityaddressRegionpostalCode `rather then values. looking what's wrong

Comment: Use `$address.= $comment->plaintext;` or `$address.= $comment->innertext;` this will returns the text.

Comment: @Manirbharathi: thanks, it gives addres with plaintext. I used plaintext and innertext both of image and phone but this both does not get printed